# Woocommerce Languages Files

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, language

I installed Woocommerce but it isn't in my selected language. On FTP I can't find any languages files to :( Do you have a downloadlink for the German translation files?

Thank you
Jan

Answer (score 0):

i run today into the same problem.

When your main Wordpress language is German than WooCommerce installs automatically the German language files.

Otherwise you have to include the translation files into "wp-content/languages/plugins". You can download them here:

(Du-Form)
https://github.com/Tech-Nomad/woocommerce-de_DE

(Sie-Form)
https://github.com/Tech-Nomad/woocommerce-de_DE_formal

Try also to un- and reinstall the WooCommerce Plugin if you didn't make a lot of changes to the theme/database with WooCommerce.